# If / else statement in PHP to show multi-format video in HTML markup

Tags: php, html, if-statement, html5-video

I want to show multi-format videos on my index.php or index.html

I set videos source/src as a variable on my index.php like below

```
<?php 
$video_1080p = "../videos/abcd-1080p.mp4";
$video_720p = "../videos/abcd-720p.mp4";
$video_480p = "../videos/abcd-480p.mp4";
$video_360p = "../videos/abcd-360p.mp4";
$video_240p = "../videos/abcd-240p.mp4";

// also add HD filter variable
$hd = "data-fluid-hd";
?>
```

This is my HTML markup and i want to show videos, according to the video source, and HD filter. And also remove <source> tag if any video variables empty.

```
<html>
<body>
<video id="123" controls style="width: 100%; height: auto;">

<source data-fluid-hd src='../videos/abcd-1080p.mp4' title='1080p' type='video/mp4' />

<source data-fluid-hd src='../videos/abcd-720p.mp4' title='720p' type='video/mp4' />

<source src='../videos/abcd-480p.mp4' title='480p' type='video/mp4' />

<source src='../videos/abcd-360p.mp4' title='360p' type='video/mp4' />

<source src='../videos/abcd-240p.mp4' title='240p' type='video/mp4' />

</video>
</body>
</html>
```

How to do it by if else statement or any other ways?

All videos are raw files (converted with FFmpeg).

Comment: If you are new to PHP, start with basics.

Comment: Many questions come to mind with this implementation, how are you identifying the video quality? is it based on filename? then you could use split() to identify the quality. Alternatively, i'm sure there's some libraries out there that help you get the video quality of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to Array and loop it instead of writing multiple `if` statements.

```
$videos = array(
  array('src' => $video_1080p, 'title' => '1080p', 'hd' => $hd),
  array('src' => $video_720p, 'title' => '720p', 'hd' => $hd),
  array('src' => $video_480p, 'title' => '480p'),
  array('src' => $video_360p, 'title' => '360p'),
  array('src' => $video_240p, 'title' => '240p')
);

foreach ($videos as $video) {
  if (!empty($video['src'])) {
    echo "<source";
    if (!empty($video['hd'])) echo " " . $video['hd'];
    echo " src='" . $video['src'] . "' title='" . $video['title'] . "' type='video/mp4' />";
  }
}
```